# How do you generate a Info.plist in Xcode since it is not able to find out?

Tags: xcode, macos

How do you generate an Info.plist in Xcode because I am getting the following error when I build my project?

error: could not read data from '../dists/xcode/Info.plist': The file “Info.plist” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file.

What should I do?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like your Info.plist file is merely lost.

Search through your project to see if there is any file with the name "`Info.plist`", or has "`Info.plist`" as part of the name (e.g. "`TopNotchCoderProjectInfo.plist`").

Once you find it, you can either reset your project settings to use the correct Info.plist file -- the path to this specific file can be entered into the Project settings:

[image: Plist Settings can be entered here]

Also, make certain the plist file exists in the list of files and folders in your project (and that it isn't "red", which is Xcode's way of telling you it's missing).